# Verifying number of method calls within a linq select expression

Tags: c#, moq, xunit

My unit test is verifying the number of times a mocked method is invoked:

**Test Setup**

```
var mockedDependency= new Mock<IDependeny>();
mockedDependency.Setup(x => x.CheckSomething(It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);

//make sure CheckSomething is called x times
                
//verify 
mockedDependency.Verify(x => x.CheckSomething(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Exactly(xtimes));
```

**Invoking CheckSomething**

This works (shows correct x number of calls):

```
//var itemsToCheck  = some array
CheckResults[] checks = new CheckResults[knownLegth];
for (int i = 0; i < checks.Length; i++)
{
   checks[i] = new CheckResults
   {
       Name = itemsToCheck[i],
       Valid = dependency.CheckSomething(itemsToCheck [i])
   };
}
```

But this does not work (shows zero calls to CheckSomething):

```
var checks = itemsToCheck .Select(x => new CheckResults
{
    Name = x,
    Valid = dependency.CheckSomething(x)
});
```

For both approaches, CheckSomething is mocked correctly, returning true.
Is there a specific reason moq's Verify does not work within the Select linq expression?
Using moq v4.15.1

Comment: `Select` don"t iterate the enumeration. You need add `.ToList()` to force the iteration.

Comment: @Vernou, thanks for pointing out the oversight. Was unit testing a controller returning ActionResult<IEnumerable<CheckResults>>, will have to call actionResult.Result.Value.ToList() in the unit tests to ensure iteration and prevent code edits in controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**
As per @Vernou's comment, directly call  ToList() in test method.

**How if fixed my problem.**

Since I was testing a controller returning ActionResult<IEnumerable>, to prevent making code changes in controller, call ToList() within unit test:

```
[Fact]
public void My_Unit_Test()
{ 
    int checks = 10; 
    string[] items= new string[checks]; 
    var mockedDependency= new Mock<IDependeny>();
    mockedDependency.Setup(x => x.CheckSomething(It.IsAny<string>()))
       .Returns(true);

     var myController= new MyController(mockedDependency.Object);
     var actionResult = myController.CallMethod(items);
     
     var actionResult = dailyStockPricesController.Verify(fileNames);

     var okResult = actionResult.Result as OkObjectResult; 
     Assert.NotNull(okResult);

     var value = (IEnumerable<FileUploadVerification>)okResult.Value;

     Assert.Equal(10, value.ToList().Count); //call ToList() at least once
     mockedDependency.Verify(x => x.CheckSomething(It.IsAny<string>()), Times.Exactly(checks));
 }
```